# How can I combine columns in pandas dataframe with duplicate names?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have got pandas dataframe which looks as following: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHwNL.png)

There are multiple columns for Australia based on the provinces, and the columns are titled Australia, Australia.1, Australia.2 and so on. It is also the case for other countries such as the USA, the UK or Canada. I want to have only one column for each of these countries. For example, I want to have one column named Australia with the sum total of values in each provinces, and I want to avoid duplicate column names. How can I do it using pandas dataframe in Python?

Comment: Are those your only columns? Look into `df.melt()`

Comment: No, my columns are all the countries in the world. For certain countries, there are values with provincial level where I get duplicate column names as stated above.

Comment: Are there any other types of columns besides the duplicated countries of the world?

Comment: No. There are only columns with country names.

Comment: Another option might be `df.T.reset_index()` Try this or `df.melt()`.

Comment: Thank you. I get a dataframe with duplicate row names (Australia, Australia.1, Australia.2, and so on) with transpose. My question is how to I sum the values in these rows/columns with duplicate names, and have them in only one row or column as total.

Comment: After some testing, this is the best code to fix your duplicate issue: `df['index'] = df['index'].str.replace('\.\d+', '')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can transpose the dataframe and reset the index. Then, remove periods and number and groupby the columns which in my example is `index`:

```
df = df.T.reset_index()
df['index'] = df['index'].str.replace('\.\d+', '')
df.iloc[:,2:] = df.iloc[:,2:].astype(float)
df = df.groupby('index').sum()
df
```

Comment: Thank you. I am able to group the country into one row. However, I am getting a concatenation of values rather than sum with the last line of the code.

Comment: @HimalayaBirShrestha please see the updated code. The first two columns should be of object data type with a `df.info()`. It sounds like the remaining columns are also of  object data type if you write `df.info()`. That means you need to change them all to float. I do this in one line with `df.iloc[:,2:] = df.iloc[:,2:].astype(float)`.